# RegExp group should not begin with special charactor

Tags: regex

I've the following RegExp

```
^.+\s.+\s(?P<authuser>.+)\s\[.+\]\s"[A-Z]+\s.+ HTTP/\d.\d"\s(?P<status>200|304|204)\s
```

How should I modify this, that It matches anything except the - (but strings which includes -) in the first group?

It should match the first two lines, but not the third:

```
37.77.82.109 - steitz [30/Mar/2014:00:22:23 +0100] "GET /eset_upd/update.ver HTTP/1.0" 304 -
37.77.82.109 - steitz-bla [30/Mar/2014:00:22:23 +0100] "GET /eset_upd/update.ver HTTP/1.0" 304 -
37.77.82.109 - - [30/Mar/2014:00:22:23 +0100] "GET /eset_upd/update.ver HTTP/1.0" 304 -
```

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks a negative look ahead solves my problem.

```
^.+\s.+\s(?P<authuser>(?!-).+)\s\[.+\]\s"[A-Z]+\s.+ HTTP/\d.\d"\s(?P<status>200|304|204)\s
```

But sure, this also do not match -bla (but this was not requested in the question)